# Could someone please explain this AS3 code line by line?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I have come across this code to insert commas in a number, and I plan to use it in my code. It works, but I would like to understand what is happening. I'm writing a wealth calculator, and I need to add commas to the number in the results.

```
    function addComma(num: uint): String {
        var str: String = "";
        while (num > 0) {
            var tmp: uint = num % 1000;
            str = (num > 999 ? "," + (tmp < 100 ? (tmp < 10 ? "00" : "0") : "") : "") + tmp + str;
            num = num / 1000;
        }
        return str;
    }
```

It works beautifully, but I want to understand it so I can write something similar if I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's walk through this line by line.

```
function addComma(num: uint): String {
```

This is self-explanatory. It declares a function called `addComma` that takes one parameter, `num`, which is an unsigned integer (a `uint`). The function returns a `String`.

```
    var str: String = "";
```

This just defines a variable called `str` that is a `String` and sets it to an empty string.

```
    while (num > 0) {
```

This loops while the variable `num` is greater than 0. The loop itself divides num by 1000 each iteration, so it will eventually reach 0 when the function completes.

```
        var tmp: uint = num % 1000;
```

This creates a temporary variable called `tmp` which is `num` modulo 1000. That is, it is the *remainder* of `num / 1000`. This allows us to get the current "segment" of digits we'll be working on—the last three digits in the number.

```
        str = (num > 999 ? "," + (tmp < 100 ? (tmp < 10 ? "00" : "0") : "") : "") + tmp + str;
```

This line is a little more tricky. It uses the *ternary* or *conditional operator*. It works like a condensed if block. Basically, `a ? b : c` is the same as `if (a) { b; } else { c; }`, but it *evaluates* to `b` and `c`'s values.

Therefore, we'll add a comma and leading digits, but only if the number is bigger than 999 (if it's smaller, then there are no more digits to process, so we don't care). We add leading zeros if `tmp` is less than 100, otherwise we might get numbers like `1,23,40` from `1023040`.

Finally, we tack on the actual value and the current accumulated value in `str` to get our new result.

```
        num = num / 1000;
```

Now we just divide `num` by 1000. Since `num` is an *integer*, this will just round down to the nearest whole number. Therefore, all the fractional components will be discarded, and we'll be able to operate on the next set of digits.

```
    }
    return str;
```

Finally, we return the final result.

```
}
```

And that's it! We're done. I'm not even sure if this is the *best* solution for the given problem, but it gets the job done. If I were to write it myself, though, I'd convert the number to a string first, *then* insert the commas. That way, you don't have to worry about inserting the leading zeros.

Comment: Thank you so much Alexis! Really appreciate it!